# pygame.mixer sound not playing when script run from command line

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi project and I have a python script that accepts some serial input and plays sounds depending on the input. I have the script set up and it works just fine when I run it from within the GUI (i.e. startx). If I log out of the GUI and try to run the script from the command line the script executes just fine but my sounds don't play. I just get a momentary static click. I can tell the script is running because I have it printing debug code and the print's work just fine. Is there a way to get the sounds to work from the command line?

I want this script to execute when the Raspberry Pi is turned on without user input which I believe means it will be running from the command line. If there is some reason the sounds simply won't play until the GUI starts up how would I set it up to load the GUI and then execute the script on startup without any user input?

This will be embedded in a prop and will play sounds when some buttons (connected through arduino i.e. serial input) are pressed. So I need a solution that will have it from power on automatically run the script and be able to play the sounds with no keyboard, mouse, or monitor attached.

Comment: You should be able to init pygame with just audio, not video. But I've not used rasberry pi.

Comment: Do you have a link to the code that you use to play the audio available anywhere?

Comment: I figured it out. The file path names need to be different when run from the command line. See my answer. Sorry I forgot to accept it because it wouldn't let me for a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was file path naming. If I have the command line test to the root directory it doesn't work but if I "cd Desktop/containingFolder" then the sounds play. I'll play with how I have the files set up in the python script so it will work.

Updating the path names fixed the issue. I just needed them to be full paths instead of relative ones.